# What's the best way to modify/compile source code of open source projects?

Tags: php, open-source, ubuntu

Like PHP and ubuntu.

Is there a convenient way to see the modification alive?

Answer (score 2):

Many open source projects are compiled with those three steps:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The first checks for dependencies and creates a makefile that matches your installation.
The second does the actual compilation and the third one installs it into /usr/bin or whereever it goes.

If you want to modify the code, I recommend you first do the above steps on the unmodified code, to make sure your tool chain actually works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Each project is different. Most projects have a "How to build" section in their documentation.

To keep up to date with changes in the code I would recommend joining the appropriate mailing list or whatever discussion mechanism the project uses.

You could also subscribe to the RSS feed of the source control or ticket/bug system used by the project.

For the two projects you mentioned have a look at the following sites:

PHP

- [Using PHP with SVN](http://php.net/svn.php)
- [Using SVN for PHP Development](http://www.php.net/svn-php.php)
- [PHP Bugs](http://bugs.php.net/)

Ubuntu

- [Ubuntu Development](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment)
- [Ubuntu Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu)